# How can I force rails to treat an oracle Date field as DateTime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, activerecord

**My problem**

Oracle 'DATE' columns actually store time as well, just with less precision than 'TIMESTAMP' (seconds vs picoseconds). I need my application to interact with this legacy schema as if the Date was a DateTime. Because rails thinks of this field as a date, its truncating the time.

**Example:**

```
2.4.1 :003 > m.send_after_ts = Time.now
 => 2018-03-15 11:45:50 -0600
2.4.1 :004 > m.send_after_ts
 => Thu, 15 Mar 2018
```

**Config Data:**

The result of `#columns`:

```
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedColumn:0x00000005501658
  @collation=nil,
  @comment=nil,
  @default=nil,
  @default_function=nil,
  @name="send_after_ts",
  @null=true,
  @object_type=false,
  @returning_id=false,
  @sql_type_metadata=
   #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SqlTypeMetadata:0x00000005501720
    @limit=nil,
    @precision=nil,
    @scale=nil,
    @sql_type="DATE",
    @type=:date>,
  @table_name="mail",
  @virtual=false>,
```

Versions:

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin17]
Rails 5.1.5
activerecord (5.1.5)
activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.8.2)
ruby-oci8 (2.2.5.1)
```

I assume there must be a mapping someplace that governs this relationship? How can I make rails cast this field as a timestamp?

**UPDATE**

Adding `attribute :send_after_ts, :datetime` to my model allows rails to treat the field as a DateTime, but causes an exception while trying to write to the db:

```
SQL (4.4ms)  INSERT INTO "MAIL" ("SEND_AFTER_TS", "ID") VALUES (:a1, :a2)  [["send_after_ts", "2018-03-15 12:58:02.635810"], ["id", 6778767]]
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: OCIError: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string: INSERT INTO "MAIL" ("SEND_AFTER_TS", "ID") VALUES (:a1, :a2)
    from (irb):3
```

I assume this is caused by the extra precision (fractional seconds), but I don't see a way to define that as part of the attribute setting.

I'm able to get around this for now by writing this field as a string, eg:

```
2.4.1 :013 > m.send_after_ts = Time.now.to_s
 => "Mar 15, 2018 12:48"
2.4.1 :014 > m.save
 => true
```

I'm still looking for a real solution.

Comment: Did you look into the "Attributes API"? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: No, I missed that in my searching. `attribute :send_after_ts, :datetime` did the trick. If you care to write that as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I may have spoken too soon. It's not writing the timestamp to the db.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the virtual attribute pattern as your interface:

```
def send_after_ts_datetime
  send_after_ts.to_datetime
end

def send_after_ts_datetime=(datetime)
  self.send_after_ts = datetime.to_s
end
```

Now you'll read from and write to the attribute using the `_datetime` methods, but your data will be stored in the original `send_after_ts` column.

```
>> m.send_after_ts_datetime = Time.now
#> "2018-03-15 15:15:49 -0600"

>> m.send_after_ts_datetime
#> Thu, 15 Mar 2018 15:15:49 -0600
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I just had to deal with this myself today, so I thought I'd share my hacky solution.

`OracleEnhancedAdapter` extends `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractAdapter`.  During its initialization, it calls its `initialize_type_map` method where it maps these types. OracleEnhancedAdapter contains an override for this, which in turn calls the superclass method inside `AbstractAdapter`. In here is where it maps the undesired date type to the oracle DATE type:

```
register_class_with_precision m, %r(date)i,      Type::Date
```

In my "fix" for this, I created an initializer in rails that overrides this method:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::OracleEnhancedAdapter.class_eval do
    # ... some other method customization
    def initialize_type_map(m)
      # other code from the AbstractAdapter implementation

      # actually make the mapping to the DateTime that you really want
      register_class_with_precision m, %r(date)i,      ActiveRecord::Type::DateTime

      # ... code from the OracleEnhancedAdapter implementation
    end
  end
end
```

The result is that oracle DATE types are now seen in rails as datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code to force Oracle "DATE" to use DateTime ruby type

```ruby
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_adapter'

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class OracleEnhancedAdapter
      alias :old_initialize_type_map :initialize_type_map
      def initialize_type_map(m = type_map)
        old_initialize_type_map(m)
        m.register_type "DATE", Type::DateTime.new
      end
    end
  end
end
```